# Limit of a sequence of a function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let, $f_{n}(x)=\dfrac{1}{n} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \sqrt {k(n-k)}{n\choose k}x^{k}(1-x)^{n-k}$ for $x\in [0,1],n=0,1,2,...$

If $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}f_{n}(x)=f(x)$ for $x\in [0,1]$, then the maximum value of $f(x)$ on $[0,1]$ is

(A) 1

(B) $\dfrac{1}{2}$

(C) $\dfrac{1}{3}$

(D) $\dfrac{1}{4}$

I want to find the value of $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}f_{n}(x)$ but I can't find it.

I only know that $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}x^{k}(1-x)^{n-k}=1$. But I can't express this sum separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_n(x)$ is nothing but a [Bernstein Polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial) of $\sqrt{x(1-x)}$.

We have that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = \sqrt{x(1-x)}$.

Thus the maximum occurs at $x = 1/2$.

***Note***: Bernstein polynomials can be used to give a constructive proof (among many proofs, constructive or non-constructive) of the Weierstrass approximation theorem. They also have a nice probabilistic interpretation, leading to a book proof of the Weierstrass approximation theorem.

Answer (score 0):

since
$$f_{n}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sqrt{\dfrac{k}{n}(1-\dfrac{k}{n})}\binom{n}{k}x^k(1-x)^{n-k}$$
and let
$$f(x)=\sqrt{x(1-x)}$$
use [Weierstrass theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem)we have
$$|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon,n\to\infty$$
so
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f_{n}(x)=f(x)=\sqrt{x(x-1)}\le\dfrac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Weierstress theorem states that for a continuous real valued function $f(x)$ there exists a polynomial $p(x)$ such that $|f(x)-p(x)|<\epsilon$. So, here for $f(x)$ how we can conclude that the polynomial must be $f_{n} (x)$ ?