# Finding the maximum value of a function expressed as the sum of an infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

let $$f_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sqrt{k(n-k)}\left(\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\right)x^{k}(1-x)^{n-k}$$
for $x\in [0,1],n=1,2,3,\cdots$ if $\lim_{n \to \infty } f_{n}(x)=f(x)$ for $x\in [0,1]$ then the maximum value of $f(x)$ on $[0,1]$ is

1. 1
2. $\frac{1}{2}$
3. $\frac{1}{3}$
4. $\frac{1}{4}$

The question seems to be hinting at using either the Cauchy-schwarz inequality in n-dimensional Euclidean space with $u_{k}=\sqrt{k(n-k)}$ & $v_{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}x^{k}(1-x)^{n-k}$ and then using the squeeze theorem to find the limit or somehow seperating the radical from the binomial expansion of $(1-x+x)^{n}$ or manipulating a maclaurin series to get to the given function but I'm stuck on how to do that.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit of a sequence of a function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1102142/limit-of-a-sequence-of-a-function)